# Is Cognito Forms free?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is Cognito Forms free and how many responses per month can I get?

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, you're right and thanks for your answer!  We are working on a pricing page to clarify things as we release paid features, like online payments, in the coming months.  Your summary from the TOS was perfect though, and we have no plans to change this.

Comment: Pricing page is now live: https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing

Answer (score 4):

It is free or chargeable according to circumstances as outlined [here](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing):

> The free tier will support unlimited forms and fields but storage will be limited to 100 MB and form entries will be limited to 500 entries per month across all forms.

Comment: You didn't need that large image